# Pesky navigation and search field won't align

Tags: css, html, forms, input

After attempting just about everything under the sun I cannot seem to get a navigation bar and a search field to align with each other.

Here is the HTML portion of the set-up:

```
<header id="header">
    <h1 class="header"></h1>
    <section id="navigationWrapper">
        <nav>
            <a class="navLink" href="/home.html">Home</a>
            <a class="navLink" href="/about.html">About</a>
            <a class="navLink" href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <section id="searchQuery">
            <form action="/search.aspx" id method="post">
                <input type="text" id="searchQuery_field" name="search" value="search">
                <input type="submit" id="searchQuery_submit" name="searchSubmit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </section>
    </section>
</header>
```

The complementing CSS:

```
/* CLASSES */
.header {color:#FFD700;}
.navLink {text-decoration:none;}

/* UNIQUE ELEMENTS */
#navigationWrapper {clear:both;}
#searchQuery form {display:inline-block;}

/* GLOBAL */
body {background-color:#f1f1f1;font-family:arial;width:100%;}
footer, header {background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;left:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:0px;padding:0px;position:fixed;right:0px;text-align:center;width:100%;}
footer {border-top:3px #FFD700 solid;bottom:0px;clear:both;} /* #FFA819 */
header {border-bottom:3px #FFD700 solid;top:0px;}
```

Browser compatibility isn't an issue since it has been decided that IE8 and older will not be supported. Any remotely useful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should create http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: what about this? http://jsfiddle.net/pWhAT/

Comment: may be like this http://jsfiddle.net/2XM5b/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I wanted the navigation links to be centered and the search field aligned more to the right. I removed the floating for the navigation and added float right for the search field, but now the links are not centered.

Comment: @OutcastCyborg like this http://jsfiddle.net/2XM5b/2/  or do you want them to in same line also.

Comment: Yes, I wanted them in the same line with the navigation links centered.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something more like this

```
<header id="header">
    <h1 class="header"></h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="navLink" href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="navLink" href="/about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="navLink" href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form action="/search.aspx" id method="post">
            <input type="text" id="searchQuery_field" name="search" value="search">
            <input type="submit" id="searchQuery_submit" name="searchSubmit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </nav>
</header>
```

cs

```
/* CLASSES */
.header {color:#FFD700;}
.navLink {text-decoration:none;}

/* UNIQUE ELEMENTS */
ul, form{float: right;}

/* GLOBAL */

body {background-color:#f1f1f1;font-family:arial;width:100%;}
footer, header {background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;left:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:0px;padding:0px;position:fixed;right:0px;text-align:center;width:100%;}
footer {border-top:3px #FFD700 solid;bottom:0px;clear:both;} /* #FFA819 */
header {border-bottom:3px #FFD700 solid;top:0px;}
```

Your use of `<section>` isn't considered to be meaningful HTML. It is more often used to describe the main content of the page.

You can also target a specific element such as `nav ul li a{text-decoration:none;}` which would prevent the need to define a `class` for every link.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to drop IE9 as well, [flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/) makes this [hilariously easy](http://jsfiddle.net/6rx3f/):

```
#navigationWrapper {
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
}
#navigationWrapper > nav {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It's kind of a pain to write all three syntaxes plus prefixes, but [this Sass mixin](https://github.com/mastastealth/sass-flex-mixin) helps on the off chance you're using a preprocessor already.